# Kendo UI stacked chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm having some problems with Kendo stacked chart - for example, for the values of: M4_IN = 1, M4_OUT = 7
the chart shows 701 on the value axis - it stacks the 7 as 700.

```
$("#monthlyChartIn").kendoChart({
                    dataSource: monthlyDS,
                    title: "aaa",
                    autoBind: true,
                    theme: "Metro",
                    legend: {visible:true},
                    seriesDefaults: {
                          type: "column",  
                          stack: true,
                          tooltip: {
                              visible: true,
                              template: "#: category# : #: value#"
                          }


                        },
                          categoryAxis: {
                              field: "Unit",
                              labels: {
                                    rotation: -90
                                  }                        
                          },
                           series: [
                           {
                          stack: "M4",
                          name: 'a',
                           field: "M4_IN",
                          },
                            {
                          stack: "M4",
                          name: 'b',
                           field: "M4_OUT",
                          },




                              ],



                        });
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does your datasource look like? I put your code in a dojo demo and seems to work fine: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/elIRO

Comment: That's the weird thing, it works in the dojo. the data source is a JSON: {"Unit": "Unit1", "M4_IN" : 1, "M4_OUT": 7} exactly like this and the schema is:

Comment: schema:
                        {
                          model: {
                                Unit: {type: "string"},
                                M4_IN: {type: "number" },
                                M4_OUT: {type: "number"},

Comment: I added the schema and it still seems to work: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/elIRO

Comment: This is exactly the weird thing - it works in the Dojo but not when I run it live.